# used a VBA object name as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

For a sloppy reason, I made a variable named 'cells' in my code like this

```
   Dim cells as Range
```

But now in all of my modules, the 'Cells' object has been replaced with the lowercase variable 'cells'.  If I type in 'Cells', the VBA editor will automatically replace the text with 'cells'.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to fix this is to rename `cells` to be `Cells`.

Comment: +1 - Similar problem with the same solution here: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=71829&page=1

Answer (score 0):

You could also just find and replace one at a time, it would be tedious though.

Comment: Won't work, the editor will replace it all back as soon as you type in one more `cells`.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger problem is that normally an unqualified use of `Cells` refers to the active sheet and thus returns a range (i.e. `ActiveSheet.Cells`) containing all of the cells on that active sheet (as long as the active sheet is a worksheet).

If your own variable called `cells` is in scope then it will take precedence over the global use of `Cells`. As both refer to a `Range` object there won't be any syntax errors - just difficult to find semantic ones.

I would rename the variable `cells` to something totally different instead. After that if Excel still changes `Cells` to `cells` then the suggestions in the link reafidy supplied above should help